# Clearing contents of memory mapped file in C#

Tags: c#

I am using MemoryMappedFile for communication between 2 programs. Program "A" creates the mmf and reads it's contents on a timer.  Program "B" writes xml data to the mmf on a timer.  I have the memory map working but I run into an issue where the previous iteration of the XML data is longer than the current and old data gets carried over to the next round.

so for simplicity lets say program B writes

aaaa

Program A will read correctly,

Then the next write from program B is:

b

Program A reads

baaa

It seems like there should be some simple way to flush the contents of the memory mapped file but I can't seem to figure it out. It's very possible that I'm totally wrong in the way I'm going about this.

Here's what I'm currently doing.

Program A:

```
using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("testmap",MemoryMappedFileRights.ReadWrite))
{

    Mutex mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("testmapmutex");
    mutex.WaitOne();
    string outputtext;
    using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream(0,0))
    {

        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        outputtext = textReader.ReadToEnd();
        textReader.Close();

    }

    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    return outputtext; //ends up in a textbox for debugging

}
```

Program B

```
using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("testmap", MemoryMappedFileRights.ReadWrite))
{

    Mutex mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("testmapmutex");
    mutex.WaitOne();

    using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream(0, 0))
    {


        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, myObjectToExport);
        textWriter.Flush();

    }
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();

}
```

Comment: I wonder whether `stream.SetLength(stream.Position);` works in this situation to truncate the file at the current position.

Comment: Your first attempt worked by accident, the MMF still contained binary zeros, XmlSerializer ignores them.  No such luck on the second attempt.  The arguments you pass to CreateViewStream() matter, you have to pass the correct size.  That's a nasty chicken-and-egg problem, that needs to go in the MMF as well.  There's also a particularly nasty problem with the XML not fitting the MMF.  You are *not* getting the benefits of an MMF here at all, few as they are in managed code, you're much better off with a named pipe.

Comment: You're right on all that. Someone pointed out that I should be using named pipes yesterday but then deleted his answer. I swapped the whole thing over today and I think it will work for me.

Comment: Should I delete this whole question since I've abandoned this strategy in favor of named pipes?

Comment: I was unable to find an acceptable solution for the same problem so my workaround has been to pass a GUID with each message, the client tracks it as LastGuid, then on deserializing if the current message Guid is the same it ignores the message. Still feels like a shitty hack workaround for something which should be straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `length` is reasonably small, you could *really* clear it out

```
textWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
textWriter.BaseStream.Write(new byte[length], 0, length);
textWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

**EDIT:** I think I misunderstood the OP's question.  The problem he was having was not with *clearing the contents* of the MMF, but with stream manipulation.  This should fix the problem:

```
textWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
textWriter.Write("");
textWriter.Flush();
```

That being said, you might want to do both.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't really worked with MemoryMappedStreams much but this question seemed interesting so I took a crack at it. I wrote a really basic windows example with two buttons (read/write) and a single text box. I didn't pass in "0, 0" to the CreateViewStream calls and I created the file with a fixed length using a call to "CreateOrOpen" and everything worked well! The following are the key pieces of code that I wrote:

**WRITE The File**

```
// create the file if it doesn't exist
if (sharedFile == null) sharedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("testmap", 1000, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);

// process safe handling
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "testmapmutex");

if (mutex.WaitOne()) {
    try {
        using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = sharedFile.CreateViewStream()) {
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.WriteLine(txtResult.Text);
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
    finally { mutex.ReleaseMutex(); }
}
```

**READ The File**

```
// create the file if it doesn't exist
if (sharedFile == null) sharedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("testmap", 1000, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);

// process safe handling
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "testmapmutex");

if (mutex.WaitOne()) {
    try {
        using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = sharedFile.CreateViewStream()) {
            var textReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            txtResult.Text = textReader.ReadToEnd();
            textReader.Close();
        }
    }
    finally { mutex.ReleaseMutex(); }
}
```

**Dispose the file (after finished)**

```
if (sharedFile != null) sharedFile.Dispose();
```

For the full example, see here: https://github.com/goopyjava/memory-map-test. Hope that helps!

**EDIT/NOTE** - If you look at the example provided you can write to the file as many times as you want and any time you read you will read exactly/only what was written last. I believe this was the original goal of the question.

Comment: You haven't solved the OP's problem at all, you only got as far as his first attempt.

Comment: @HansPassant If you try out the test program I posted it actually "clears the file" every time you run the read or write block of code. In essence by writing null characters beyond the end of the string this seems to work - not just the first time but every time after that as well. In other words, I did solve the heart of the issue which is writing multiple times to the same shared file. Please download/run the code and I think you should see the same results.

Comment: "Clears the file" is instrumental, don't omit that from your code.  The point of an MMF is efficiency.  Having to "clear" a lot of bytes just to transfer 1 byte is not efficient.  That "clear" works is just an accident, XmlSerializer happens to ignore binary zeros.  That a 1000 bytes work is just an accident as well, clearly there can be a lot more XML than that.  Too many accidents.

Comment: @HansPassant You are correct, having a fixed size file could be a problem. That is something the OP didn't ask so I didn't address specifically. We didn't see how they created their original file so I don't know how they handled this criteria. As to the "clear", the point of my example is you don't need to do this at all - just terminate with a special character (eg '\0'). In my example, if you terminate with a null character on serialize that would be sufficient to allow reading/writing any number of times without ever needing a clear. I assume the xml serialize routines have similar options.

Comment: Hey thanks for looking into this, I had the same idea originally to terminate on a special character but I couldn't figure it out. Someone pointed out yesterday that named pipes are a better fit for my application and I switched it all over today.  Looks like that answer got deleted though.